# Is it possible to use Visual Studio's Winforms Editor in your application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I need to develop a HMI builder for SCADA application I am developing. I need something like Visual studio's winform editor. Is it available as a control so that it can be used in your application? What else can be used?

Comment: As far as I am aware their designer for winforms is not something you can use as a control at all. However their controls within the editor such as Textbutton, alongside all controls are something you can generate programmatically. So its possible to create your own version of their designer, using the controls it offers.

Comment: Take a look at [Hosting Windows Forms Designers](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4351/hosting-windows-forms-designers/) or [Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419204547/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163871.aspx)

Comment: Microsoft does not give you a way to host Visual Studio's WinForms editor, but SharpDevelop IDE has an open source clone, http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx Anyway you need to dig its code base.